# Before syncdb, delete field from standard Django model

Tags: django, model, del, syncdb

This is a follow-up question on [Delete field from standard Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249820/delete-field-from-standard-django-model). In short: a field can be dynamically deleted from a model that is already created, in this case the field User.email . So field email would be deleted from User without changing the code for User. See code below for example.

I can dynamically delete a a field from a model(1), but that happens when the server starts and is undone when it exists. Since syncdb doesn't require the server to be running, and generally seems to ignore the deletion code (somehow), this approach doesn't prevent the field from appearing in the database(2).

Is there a way to do delete the field from the model (without changing the file it's in, as it's a Django model), in a way that also makes it not appear in the database?

Thanks in advance!

Mark

**EDIT**: I problem is *not* that I am deleting the text "`m = models.IntegerField()`" from the model file and want the field removed from the database. The problem is that I am using the code below to remove a field from a model that has *already been declared in another file*. I do not think that creating a migration with South for every time I run syncdb is a solution(3).

*Additional information:*

- 1) Currently, the code is in models.py, but I suppose [Where to put Django startup code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781383/where-to-put-django-startup-code) works.
- 2) I can delete it on post_syncdb signal with custom query, but I hope for something more elegant... Or elegant at all, more accurately.
- 3) If it even works at all, because obviously syncdb is still seeing the 'removed' field), so I think South would to as it's still somehow there.

This is the code (models.py):

```
class A(models.Model):
    m = models.IntegerField()

for i, f in enumerate(A._meta.fields):
    if f.name == 'm':
        del A._meta.fields[i]
        break

class B(A):
    n = models.IntegerField()

for i, f in enumerate(B._meta.fields):
    if f.name == 'm':
        del B._meta.fields[i]
        break
```

*EDIT: I checked (with print) and the deletion code **is** executed on syncdb. It is executed before tables are created*

Comment: Consider using something like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to handle changes in your schema.

Comment: [South](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/) is definitively the best way.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, seems like a useful tool. However, the problem is with deleting fields from model classes after they are defined.

Comment: With South you  could create migration and apply this migration easily. So, your problem could be resolved easily : http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part1.html#changing-the-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django does a lot of meta class magic and i would guess that the meta class is responsible for defining the database table to back your model. Subsequently just deleting the field is not enough to alter the generated table.

as several people have pointed out, [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) is the way to deal with these problems.

Comment: Just for clarity: is it correct that the idea of South is to fix differences between models and the actual database? Because my problem seems to be that (at the time the database is altered), the model is not the way I want to the database to be. So I don't think South really solves the problem. Or do I misunderstand South?

Comment: south is for managing changes to the database after the initial `syncdb`. rather than trying patch the model, let syncdb run on its own and then create a migration to change the db.