# update an object after deleting a value from it

Tags: django, python-2.7

i have  an object say it as `productObj`.
when I am iterating through this object if a particular condition is met I have to delete that value from that object.

something like

```
for data in productObj:
    if data.count > 0:
        data.delete()
```

if the count is greater than zero the data value should be deleted and the `productObj` should be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just working off your own code, then

```
if data.count > 0:
    data.count = None
#continue with some stuff and lastly call .save()
productObj.save()
```

should suffice.

Calling `.delete()` will, in Django, remove the entire object.

However if you want to delete the attribute of that said object, you're gonna have a bad time, especially when you're working of an object that inherits from `models.Model` but let's go ahead and do it anyways

```
del productObj.count #from the object
```

and if you want it stripped from the model you would have to delete it from the models `_meta` fields which would be the property -> `Model._meta.fields`

Daniel Roseman [explains it brilliantly here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249820/delete-field-from-standard-django-model)