# Django - Delete particular field data from model

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I am trying to delete a field's data from Django model. Suppose I have a model named **UserData** and I want to delete **city** field for record_Id = 1, without deleting the data from other fields for record_Id = 1. I used:

```
UserData.objects.filter(city="London").delete()
```

but it deletes the whole record. I tried this method on SO, but gives attribute error [Delete field from standard Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249820/delete-field-from-standard-django-model) .

Let me know how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to delete the value of specific field in a row, then it is termed as updating the field's content to `null` value and not deleting the field. In this case, if you want to update the field's value to `null`, use following statement.

```
UserData.objects.filter(record_Id=1).update(city=None)
```

Comment: it's truely a sql problem